# Not able to deploy Node server in Elasticbeanstark

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I have a server written in ES6 which i need to run on ElasticBeanstalk, whenever i run it, I have these errors

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
/var/app/current/app.js:1
import express from 'express';
```

I have used babel, and my Package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "blik-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Application backend for Blik.ai",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Blik tech team",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.528.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.1.6-alpha.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.12",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/blikdotai/blik-app.git"
  }
}
```

And the .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  }
```

I am not getting why it's throwing the error when it is running locally.
Please help

Comment: There is not enough info about your setup here, but my wild guess is that you're transpiling your app on runtime when you run it on development, but you're not doing it before building the bundle you deploy to elasticbeanstalk

Comment: Yes, it works on local though, i know its not recommended, but it works right ?

Comment: Just add a task to build the transpiled version of your app, and deploy the transpiled one

Comment: And how to do that ? :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your project before deploying it, add the following commands to your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node index.js",
  "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
  "build": "babel -d ./build ./src",
  "serve": "NODE_ENV=production node build/index.js"
},
```

Use `yarn clean` (or `npm run clean` if you use that) to clean it up, then `yarn build` to compile it.

Finally, you'll get a brand new `build/` directory that you definitely want to add to your `.gitignore` if you follow good git practices.

This `build/` directory is where your compiled app lives, so that's what you want to deploy to elasticbeanstalk.

Your command to start the server is `yarn serve`

Comment: Can u please explain what the use of ./build in build ?

Comment: it's the directory where you are going to put your compiled (technically, transpiled) files

Comment: Well, however, it did point me in the right direction, it didnt solved, i solved it by diff approch, i will answer this question shortly